# For nextJS installation npx create-next-app stuck on installation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

The create-next-app isn't responding it is stuck midway through the installation with zero installation progress and its been like this for more than 10 mins

[image]

can someone pls give a solution for this?

Comment: make sure your internet connection is working. and you can always cancel it and try again.

Comment: Restart your PC and try clearing cache `npm cache clean –force`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it happens to me very often too, usually i cancel installation by control + c, and reinstall which works fine

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue and I fixed it updating my Node version, from 14 to 18 (`18.16.1`

Answer (score 1):

For me I was trying to run it in Git Bash and it would not show the progress bar, stuck on `-eslint-config-next`. Worked fine when running in VSC terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Update your node version and theres a good chance it'll start working.